# tkinter: see() makes text disappear

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am having this weird problem in tkinter. Basically I am using a text widget to output certain messages from my application using a python logging object. The corresponding Handler looks like this:

```
class MessageHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, msg_widget, level=logging.NOTSET):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self, level)

        self.__msg_widget = msg_widget

    def emit(self, record):
        self.__msg_widget.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.__msg_widget.insert('end', '\n' + record.getMessage())
        self.__msg_widget.see('end linestart')
        self.__msg_widget.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

Here msg_widget is a tk.Text object. What happens however is that sometimes the text content completely disappears, requiring manual scrolling (using the mouse) to make it reappear. This does not happen if I uncomment the line

```
self.__msg_widget.see('end linestart')
```

Does anyone have an idea where this behavior might come from?

Comment: The .see should have nothing to do with this. From Doc: see(index)
This method returns true if the text located at the index position is visible.

Comment: [Tcl/tk doc(man page)](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/text.htm#M123) states that, _Adjusts the view in the window so that the character given by index is completely visible. If index is already visible then the command does nothing. If index is a short distance out of view, the command adjusts the view just enough to make index visible at the edge of the window. If index is far out of view, then the command centers index in the window._

Comment: If it makes the text scroll out of view, the only reason it can do that is if there are a bunch of blank lines at the of the widget. Are you inserting a bunch of blank lines?

Comment: @ErikŠťastný: you are wrong about the `see` command. What documentation are you reading? Whatever you are reading, it is wrong.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm

Comment: @BryanOakley it does not seem to scroll the text out of view, it simply is not drawn for some reason... I added a .strip() to make sure that I don't accidentally add some empty lines, but that did not make any difference.

Comment: @ErikŠťastný I think this information is outdated. I am not getting anything back from the see-method, and the [docs for the latest version](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.see-method) (8.6) also does not specify anything.

Comment: @ErikŠťastný: that tutorial is incorrect. Here's the canonical documentation: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M133

Comment: Are some of your ``emit()`` calls coming from a different thread, perhaps?  That's something that Tkinter doesn't really like.

Comment: @jasonharper that was indeed the problem, thank you very much. I have changed the code to generate events for the UI thread instead.